# How to include PHP files in a compatible way for packaging with and without Phar?

Tags: php, require, phar

Given a PHP application with the following structure:

```
/
    lib/
        mylib.php
    web/
        index.php // includes "mylib.php" with: require_once __DIR__ . "/../lib/mylib.php"
```

I am trying to cover the following cases at the same time with the same source base:

1. **No Phar**: Being able to use the application as is, with the *DocumentRoot* pointing on *web/* and redirecting all requests to *index.php*.
2. **Minimal Phar**: Being able to produce a phar that contains only *web/index.php* and that would be saved as: *web/application-minimal.phar*.
3. **Full Phar**: Being able to produce a phar that contains both the content of *lib* directory and *web/index.php* and that would be saved as: *web/application-full.phar*.

In the case of phar files, all requests would be redirected to the phar file itself.

Is it possible to achieve all those use cases while not having to change the *require_once*?

I tried different approaches (relative/absolute) to include *lib/mylib.php* from *web/index.php", as well as trying some tricks with *Phar::mount()*. None of my attempts succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Simply rely on your include path.

Don't do:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/../lib/mylib.php";
```

but:

```
require_once "mylib.php";
```

and set the include path at the beginning of your script:

```
set_include_path(__DIR__ . '/../lib/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

Comment: That will for sure not work for several reasons:
1. set_include_path() from inside the PHAR would lead to the exact same problem, ```__DIR__``` being ```"phar://.../path/to/phar"``` while the library would not be in the PHAR file.
2. libraries often contains tons of different files across directories, you just can't simply add every directories, that would be extremely slow (all entries in paths would be scanned to find the file), and would not work: eg. ```Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/Loader.php``` & ```Symfony/Component/Templating/Loader/Loader.php```, including ```Loaded.php```, really?

Comment: I talk about PSR-0 compatible autoloading, and you should of course set different include paths depending if you are in the phar or not.